# Global Variables only Called Once then Lost their Scope

Tags: variables, scope, global, adobe-indesign, extendscript

I Have a Problem with my Script and hope helping me, and thanks in advance, i still learning javascript and try to learn somthing new everyday, i have a script that draw modeless interface (palette) and have button including (option) that make another new palette (for options), i made the variables as globals for the option palette, but the problem is the global variables is only called once!, and the script lose the global variable scope!.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wZA6.jpg)

so my question is how to make the variables not losing its scope and retain in the memory? as long the script run, as an Example if the user move the slider and  hit (Show alert due options) its only run once and then lose the scope, even the slider no longer interact with the user and update text box, please test the code to see the problem, and thank again for any help or advice.

Best
M.Hasanain

```js
//Global Variables only Called Once then Lost their Scope!
#targetengine "session1";
var w = new Window("palette", {independent:true}); //Main Palette Windows
var findoptions = new Window("palette"); //Options Palette

function Main() {
    // Check to see whether any InDesign documents are open.
    // If no documents are open, display an error message.
    if (app.documents.length > 0) {
        var myDoc = app.activeDocument;
    }else{
        // No documents are open, so display an error message.
        alert("No InDesign documents are open. Please open a document and try again.");
    }
}

//---------------------------------------------------------
//Making Palettes Windows
//---------------------------------------------------------
#targetengine "session1";
var w = new Window("palette", {independent:true}); //Main Palette Windows
var findoptions = new Window("palette"); //Options Palette
//gqmanager is the (GREP Query Manager) outside the main Function
w.text = "Test the Connection Between Global Variables and Palettes";
w.preferredSize.width = 500;
w.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];  //"left";
w.orientation = "column"; //"row"; 
w.spacing = 10;
w.margins = 16;

//Parent - Input Panel Prepare
var InputPanel = w.add("panel", undefined, undefined, { name: "panel1" });
InputPanel.text = "Text Find : ";
InputPanel.preferredSize.width = 1000;
InputPanel.orientation = "row";
InputPanel.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
InputPanel.spacing = 10;
InputPanel.margins = 16;

//Children -  input Panel Inside Prepare
var myInputPanelInside = InputPanel.add("group", undefined, { name: "myInput" });
//--Adding Find What
myInputPanelInside.add("statictext", undefined, "Find What :");
//myInputPanelInside.alignment = "center";
var myGREPString = myInputPanelInside.add("edittext", undefined, "SAMPLE");
myGREPString.helpTip = "Enter Your Text"
myGREPString.characters = 20;
myGREPString.enabled = true;
myGREPString.preferredSize.width = 460;

var Button1 = myInputPanelInside.add("button", undefined, "Options");

//Parent - Radio Panel Prepare
var RadioPanel = w.add("panel", undefined, undefined, { name: "panel2" });
RadioPanel.text = "Select Desired Option : ";
RadioPanel.preferredSize.width = 1000;
RadioPanel.orientation = "row";
RadioPanel.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
RadioPanel.spacing = 10;
RadioPanel.margins = 16;

//Children -  input Panel Inside Prepare
var myRadioPanelInside = RadioPanel.add("group", undefined, { name: "myRadio" });
myRadioPanelInside.preferredSize.width = 500;
myRadioPanelInside.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];

//Adding Radio Buttons 
var radio1 = myRadioPanelInside.add("radiobutton", undefined, "Option 1");
var radio2 = myRadioPanelInside.add("radiobutton", undefined, "Option 2");
var radio3 = myRadioPanelInside.add("radiobutton", undefined, "Option 3");
radio1.preferredSize.width = 200;
radio2.preferredSize.width = 200;
radio3.preferredSize.width = 200;
//Previous Default Condition
radio1.value = true;

var myButtonGroup = w.add("group");
myButtonGroup.alignment = "center";

var Button2 = myButtonGroup.add("button", undefined, "Show Alert Due Options");
var Button3 = myButtonGroup.add("button", undefined, "Exit");

Button1.onClick = function () {
    CalltheFindOptions();
    }
Button2.onClick = function () { Find(); };
function Find() {
    doRadioButtonOpt();
}

Button3.onClick = function() {Canceled();};
function Canceled() {
    ExitSure();
}

//After Drawing Interface
var a = w.show();

function ExitSure() {
  var a = w.close();
  exit(0);
}

//User Selection for Radio Buttons
function doRadioButtonOpt() {
    myDoc = app.activeDocument; 
  if (radio1.value == true) {
    TestVars();
    }
}

function TestVars() {
    #targetengine "session1";
    var myDoc = app.activeDocument
    var TimeMs = Number(SliderControlText.text); //Converting Text to Number
    //Show Results Found as User Wish
if (DontShowResults.value == true) { //no Show only Apply
    alert("you Select not to Show Results!");
            }else{ //Direct Show and Apply
        if (ShowResultsDirect.value == true) {
    alert("you Select to Show Results in real time!");
            }else{ //Show and Apply By WaitinhTime!
                if (ShowResults.value == true) { //Show and Apply
            alert("you Select to Show Results with Specific time!");
            $.sleep(TimeMs); //Wait ms
                    }
                }
            }
alert("Do you need somthing else?, try again", "Finish Report");
}

var DontShowResults; 
var ShowResultsDirect; 
var ShowResults; 
var SliderControlText;
var slider;
//--------------------------------------------Building the Find Options Palette-----------------------------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
function CalltheFindOptions() {
#targetengine "session1";
//Find Options Window
findoptions.text = "Find Options";
//Parent - Input Panel Prepare
SelectPanel = findoptions.add("panel", undefined, undefined, { name: "panel1" });
SelectPanel.text = " Find Options : ";
SelectPanel.preferredSize.width = 1000;
SelectPanel.orientation = "row";
SelectPanel.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
SelectPanel.spacing = 10;
SelectPanel.margins = 16;

//Children -  input Panel Inside Prepare
mySelectPanelInside = SelectPanel.add("group", undefined, { name: "mySelOpt" });
DontShowResults = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Don't Show Results");
DontShowResults.value = true; //by Default
DontShowResults.alignment = "left"; 

ShowResultsDirect = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Show Results");
ShowResultsDirect.value = false; //by Default

ShowResults = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Show Results Delayed in milliseconds(Ms) :");
ShowResults.value = false; //by Default

//Adding Slider to Control MS Time
SliderControlText = mySelectPanelInside.add ("edittext", undefined, 10, {readonly: false}); //read only prevent user Entering Nums
SliderControlText.characters = 3;
slider = mySelectPanelInside.add ("slider {minvalue: 1, maxvalue: 100, value: 10}");

//Slider Listener Plus SliderControl Text Listener
slider.onChanging = function () {SliderControlText.text = slider.value;} //Listen to Slider
var c = findoptions.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to use as global variables values rather than the objects. And you can change the values of global variables by `onClick` events.

Here is the bottom part of your code (the rest part of the code wasn't changed):

```
...

function TestVars() {
    #targetengine "session1";
    var myDoc = app.activeDocument
    var TimeMs = Number(SliderControlText_text); //Converting Text to Number
    //Show Results Found as User Wish
    if (DontShowResults_value == true) { //no Show only Apply
        alert("you Select not to Show Results!");
    } else { //Direct Show and Apply
        if (ShowResultsDirect_value == true) {
            alert("you Select to Show Results in real time!");
        } else { //Show and Apply By WaitinhTime!
            if (ShowResults_value == true) { //Show and Apply
                alert("you Select to Show Results with Specific time!");
                $.sleep(TimeMs); //Wait ms
            }
        }
    }
    alert("Do you need somthing else?, try again", "Finish Report");
}

// values! not objects
var DontShowResults_value   = true;
var ShowResultsDirect_value = false;
var ShowResults_value       = false;
var SliderControlText_text  = '10';
var slider_value            = 10;
//--------------------------------------------Building the Find Options Palette-----------------------------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
function CalltheFindOptions() {
    #targetengine "session1";
    //Find Options Window
    findoptions.text = "Find Options";
    //Parent - Input Panel Prepare
    SelectPanel = findoptions.add("panel", undefined, undefined, {
        name: "panel1"
    });
    SelectPanel.text = " Find Options : ";
    SelectPanel.preferredSize.width = 1000;
    SelectPanel.orientation = "row";
    SelectPanel.alignChildren = ["center", "center"];
    SelectPanel.spacing = 10;
    SelectPanel.margins = 16;

    //Children -  input Panel Inside Prepare
    var mySelectPanelInside = SelectPanel.add("group", undefined, {
        name: "mySelOpt"
    });
    var DontShowResults = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Don't Show Results");
    DontShowResults.value = DontShowResults_value; //by Default
    DontShowResults.alignment = "left";
    // change the global variable by click
    DontShowResults.onClick = function() { DontShowResults_value = DontShowResults.value }

    var ShowResultsDirect = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Show Results");
    ShowResultsDirect.value = false; //by Default

    // change the global variable by click
    ShowResultsDirect.onClick = function() { ShowResultsDirect_value = ShowResultsDirect.value }

    var ShowResults = mySelectPanelInside.add("checkbox", undefined, "Show Results Delayed in milliseconds(Ms) :");
    ShowResults.value = ShowResults_value; //by Default

    // change the global variable by click
    ShowResults.onClick = function() { ShowResults_value = ShowResults.value }

    //Adding Slider to Control MS Time
    // SliderControlText = mySelectPanelInside.add("edittext", undefined, 10, {
    var SliderControlText = mySelectPanelInside.add("edittext", undefined, SliderControlText_text, {
        readonly: false
    }); //read only prevent user Entering Nums
    SliderControlText.characters = 3;
    var slider = mySelectPanelInside.add("slider {minvalue: 1, maxvalue: 100, value: 10}");

    // change slider every time as numbers is changes
    SliderControlText.onChanging = function() {slider.value = SliderControlText.text};

    //Slider Listener Plus SliderControl Text Listener
    slider.onChanging = function () {
        SliderControlText.text = slider.value;

        // change the global variable by onChange
        SliderControlText_text = SliderControlText.text;
    } //Listen to Slider

    findoptions.show();
}
```

It seems it works as intended.

As far as I can tell (I can be wrong), the cause of the problem was that the objects `ShowResultsDirect`, `ShowResultsDirect`, etc, disappears as soon as you close the palette. Because they are elements of the palette. They can't keep values if the palette is closed. That why they worked well only when you open the palette first time.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuri for your help, that's excellent but the slider still lose the scope after first run? can you help me fixing that?

Comment: It's the same. Just change the line: `SliderControlText = mySelectPanelInside.add("edittext", undefined, 10, {` with `var SliderControlText = mySelectPanelInside.add("edittext", undefined, SliderControlText_text, {`

Comment: And probably it makes sense to add the line to change the slider when you change numbers in the text field: `SliderControlText.onChanging = function() {slider.value = SliderControlText.text};` I've updated my answer